Why listen_addresses not changing in PostgreSQL?
I'm trying to ENABLE remote client access on my PostgreSQL 12 database (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS).
I've changed postgresql.conf on both paths /var/lib/postgresql/12/main and /etc/postgresql/12/main this way:
listen_addresses = '*'

Of course also add my ip in pg_hba.conf
I've also tried:
root@localhost:/# sudo -u postgres psql
psql (12.20 (Ubuntu 12.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# ALTER SYSTEM SET LISTEN_ADDRESSES='*';
ALTER SYSTEM

And after many restarts (of postgreSQL and even whole vnc) anyway I'm getting this:
root@localhost:/# sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW listen_addresses;'
 listen_addresses
------------------
 localhost
(1 row)

And pgAdmin 4 on my PC also tell me:

Unable to connect to server: connection timeout expired

I even tried to reinstall postgreSQL - no effect 
Why so? What is wrong?
Colleagues, please give me an advice how to solve this problem?
UPD: Also tried with inactive firewall - no effect...

Looks like there is not even a network connection to the server, you would have gotten a different error message. Check your firewalls

One of the first times I'd forget to add my ip in pg_hba.conf and saw message something about "your ip is not in listener list". I doubt it would have given such a message if the firewall was blocking the connection.
Anyway, when I'm trying to make smth like sudo -u postgres psql -h <my_ip_address> from vnc terminal there also no connection. So I appreciate Your attempt to help me, but I don't think the problem is in the firewall.

Perhaps your Postgres instance uses the configuration file in a different location. Check this and this.

If you mean this? sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW config_file;' config_file  /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf   I've already tried to edit this file as ypu can see... Thanks

You need to restart PostgreSQL to change listen_addresses.

I wrote above that restarts had no effect...

The 'ALTER SYSTEM' version works for me in v12 (after a restart).  Maybe whatever control code you use to do the restart also happens to blow away "postgresql.auto.conf" file.

There is also a postgresql.auto.conf file :
postgresql.auto.conf is a configuration file with the same format as postgresql.conf, but which is located in the data directory and is managed by PostgreSQL itself (via the ALTER SYSTEM command) or client applications (e.g. pg_basebackup in PostgreSQL 12 and later). Normally it should not be edited manually.
postgresql.auto.conf is always evaluated last, so configuration settings stored here will always override settings in other files.
https://pgpedia.info/p/postgresql-auto-conf.html
